# Why are the wrong values printing from my dictionaries within a list in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am accessing dictionaries within lists with a JSON structure in Python.  I'd like to be able to access values from each dictionary index.  In the code below I would like to access the `[1]` index of values, however when printing to test if the right values are captured, nothing is printed, and when I print the `[0]` index, the `[3]` index prints of the second list/dictionary in the JSON below.

So in the code below I would like to be able to traverse the 2nd dictionary in each list and use the values from them

```
try:
        k_bulky_item_2 = ' '
        k_bulky_count_2 = ' '
        k_bulky_name_2 = ' '
        k_bulky_comm_2 = ' '
        for sr in BulkyItem:
          if("BulkyItem" in BulkyItem):
            lbuklyitem311 = BulkyItem["BulkyItem"]
            for BulkyItem in lbuklyitem311:
                k_bulky_item_2= BulkyItem['BulkyItemType']
                k_bulky_count_2 = BulkyItem['BulkyItemCount']
                k_bulky_comm_2= BulkyItem['Type']
                k_bulky_name_2= BulkyItem['Name']
                if BulkyItem == lbuklyitem311[1]:
                    k_bulky_item_2= k_bulky_item_2
                    k_bulky_count_2 = k_bulky_count_2
                    k_bulky_name_2 =k_bulky_name_2
                    k_bulky_comm_2 = k_bulky_comm_2
                if k_bulky_comm_2 == 'Bulky Items':
                    k_bulky_comm_2 = 1
    except:
        print "No Bulky Information_2"


        print k_bulky_count_2
```

JSON:

```
{
    "ListOfServiceRequest": {
        "ServiceRequest": [
            {
                "AddressVerified": "Y",
                "SRNumber": "1-22958901",
                "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
                    "BulkyItem": [
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Carpet",
                            "CollectionLocation": "",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN1",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070620151727112061"
                        },
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Mattress",
                            "CollectionLocation": "",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Dead End",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN1",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070620151727112072"
                        },
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Wood Bundles",
                            "CollectionLocation": "",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Side Street",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN1",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070620151727112083"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "AddressVerified": "Y",
                "SRNumber": "1-22396541",
                "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
                    "BulkyItem": [
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "2",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Bookcase",
                            "CollectionLocation": "",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Curb",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "49448",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "Charles",
                            "ContactLastName": "Campbell",
                            "Name": "063020151340347731"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "AddressVerified": "Y",
                "SRNumber": "1-22888701",
                "ListOfLa311BarricadeRemoval": {

                },
                "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
                    "BulkyItem": [
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "100",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
                            "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN2",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR Supervisor",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070520152329321221"
                        },
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "500",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Bed Frame (wood)",
                            "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "Y",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN2",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR Supervisor",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070520152329321222"
                        },
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "400",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Bicycle",
                            "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN2",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR Supervisor",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070520152329321233"
                        },
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "370",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Bird Cage (Plastic)",
                            "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN2",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR Supervisor",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070520152329321244"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "AddressVerified": "Y",
                "SRNumber": "1-22666161",
                "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
                    "BulkyItem": [
                        {
                            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
                            "BulkyItemType": "Bicycle",
                            "CollectionLocation": "",
                            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
                            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                            "Type": "Bulky Items",
                            "SpecialRule": "",
                            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "MYLA-SAN2",
                            "DriverFirstName": "",
                            "DriverLastName": "",
                            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                            "TruckNo": "",
                            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                            "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                            "PurposeofSR": "",
                            "ContactFirstName": "CSR Supervisor",
                            "ContactLastName": "BOS",
                            "Name": "070320150729351771"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to be clear what `BulkyItem` actually contains.  Is it the root JSON object?  Try bringing up a debugger and figure out the path to the desired object/values you want to use and construct the method.  Also,  a casual glance showed that you have `for sr in BulkyItem:` and then `if("BulkyItem" in BulkyItem):`, don't you mean `if "BulkyItem" in sr:`?

Comment: No "BulkyItem" is an inner dictionary, while BulkyItem is list of dictionaries.

Comment: Then update the question to include what is the actual contents of the variable `BulkyItem` for a given particular instance of a given run of the software because your question is completely opaque and unclear.  Also as I said if you are running a forloop against the outer object and then within it do a check for a key existence it will **always** return either `True` or `False` for _all_ runs so it is either wrong or unneeded.

Comment: That can be found in the JSON, you will see that "BulkyItem" is a list of dictionaries under "ListOfLa311BulkyItem"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's break down the relevant section of code with data.... actually can't do that, because your code is a complete mess where you reused the same variable name for all levels of access.  You can't do that, that makes the program as confused as you are.  Anyway, starting from beginning:

```
for sr in BulkyItem:
```

I am going to assume this line is to grab the list of `"ServiceRequest"`s?  In that case `BulkyItem` at this level should be `JSON["ListOfServiceRequest"]["ServiceRequest"]`, as per:

```
"ListOfServiceRequest": {
    "ServiceRequest": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Otherwise you are just iterating through keys for a dictionary but you are accessing the following values like that...  also since you reassign `BulkyItem` further down things get absolutely confusing, but try to follow.

So now, in the first iteration `sr` should contain something like:

```
{
    "AddressVerified": "Y",
    "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
        "BulkyItem": [...]
    ...
}
```

Cool, now we see that you can check for membership using `if("BulkyItem" in BulkyItem):`, which is completely wrong, and also remember that `BulkyItem` is `JSON["ListOfServiceRequest"]["ServiceRequest"]` under my assumption on how your code works (your comment suggests that `BulkyItem` is actually something further down, but this is only because you are confused about what you wrote.)

```
    if "BulkyItem" in BulkyItem:
        lbuklyitem311 = BulkyItem["BulkyItem"]
```

Again, what is `BulkyItem` here?  Does BulkyItem["BulkyItem"] actually mean anything at this level?  At least `lbuklyitem311` suggests it's a value of the key `"ListOfLa311BulkyItem"`.  Let's assume that.

```
        for BulkyItem in lbuklyitem311:
```

This is where everyone gets confused as to what you are doing, however if you got the code above levels correct your code would actually have iterated to here, instead of simply not get here (and results in `KeyError`).

So, let's try this again, with correction.  The variable `JSON` will contain the data (with closing braces corrected) listed in your JSON: section.

```
>>> for sr in JSON['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
...     lbuklyitem311 = sr['ListOfLa311BulkyItem']
...     if 'BulkyItem' in lbuklyitem311:
...         for bulkyitem in lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem']:
...             k_bulky_item_2 = bulkyitem['BulkyItemType']
...             k_bulky_count_2 = bulkyitem['BulkyItemCount']
...             k_bulky_comm_2 = bulkyitem['Type']
...             k_bulky_name_2 = bulkyitem['Name']
... 
>>> print k_bulky_count_2
1
```

The above will at least get you started on whatever convoluted business logic you are trying to achieve.  Don't try to reuse variable names especially within a for-loop because that's literally yanking the carpet underneath a pile of vases and breaking everything.

Oh one last thing, you can simply eliminate membership check and reduce the indentation clutter by doing this instead:

```
>>> for sr in JSON['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
...     lbuklyitem311 = sr['ListOfLa311BulkyItem']
...     for bulkyitem in lbuklyitem311.get('BulkyItem', []):
```

Defaults to an empty list if calling `lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem']` normally results in a `KeyError`, which the for loop will effectively do nothing.

Further to this:

> In the JSON above there are multiple dictionaries in a list, I would like to identify in each list the [1] index of BulkyItemCount I am doing this because I need to map each of these to a NumPytoFeatureClass in ArcGIS. So you see there are multiple BulkyItemCounts for each Service Request number, I need to track all of these, per Name field which is a unique ID for each dictionary. So if looking at the JSON, the first list [1] index BulkyItemCount is 1 and the second list BulkyItemCount is 500.
>
> I use [0] index (if [1] is not found)..so you understand what I am after.

It isn't hard if you spend a bit of time thinking about it at with what you already have.  You have `lbuklyitem311` that could have `lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem'] which have the list, just poke at it however you want to.

```
>>> for sr in JSON['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
...     lbuklyitem311 = sr['ListOfLa311BulkyItem']
...     if 'BulkyItem' in lbuklyitem311:
...         if len(lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem'] == 1)
...             # do something with lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem'][0]['BulkyItemCount']
...         elif len(lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem'] > 1)
...             # do something with lbuklyitem311['BulkyItem'][1]['BulkyItemCount']
```

Comment: So in your example above, how can I successfully access each dictionary in a list??

Comment: You can access all items within a list by iterating through it as you had before.  The current item (whether string, dict, list, object) will be bound to whatever variable you named in `for ... in`

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question, I would like to access say `ItemCount` for the second dictionary in each list and give that a variable name, such as `ItemCount_2`

Comment: Yes, because your code is ambiguous and your question was unclear.  You have many dictionaries nested, what is the second dictionary?  What are the paths for the related objects?  Also there is no items identified by `"ItemCount"`, only `"BulkyItemCount"`.  What are you trying to do with that value? Why are you doing this?  Answer these questions first will help you figure out what you need to do.

Comment: In the JSON above there are multiple dictionaries in a list, I would like to identify in each list the [1] index of `BulkyItemCount`  I am doing this because I need to map each of these to a NumPytoFeatureClass in ArcGIS.  So you see there are multiple `BulkyItemCounts` for each Service Request number, I need to track all of these, per `Name` field which is a unique ID for each dictionary.  So if looking at the JSON, the first list [1] index `BulkyItemCount` is 1 and the second list `BulkyItemCount` is 500.

Comment: What about the third?  There is no [1] index.

Comment: yeah, so that's where I use [0] index..so you understand what I am after.

Comment: Updated.  Seriously you can think this through.  Note that it wasn't even hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82550/discussion-between-geoffreygis-and-metatoaster).